# Is a floating mortar bed an acceptable way to install natural cleft flagstone on a concrete slab that has a long crack?

Tags: patio

I like the features of a [floating mortar bed](https://www.tcnatile.com/faqs/69-cleavage-membrane.html).

> Thick-bed installations are based on the traditional method of packing
> a mortar bed over a surface before installing the tile. The tile is
> adhered to the mortar bed either while the mortar bed is green (just
> beginning to dry) or after the mortar bed has cured. The mortar bed
> may be reinforced with wire and either set over a cleavage membrane
> (that allows the mortar bed to "float" free of the substrate) or
> bonded to the substrate; hence, the use of the terms "floating mortar
> bed" or "bonded mortar bed".

That site refers to "tile":

> In the case of the floating mortar bed, the tile layer is unaffected
> by minor cracking and movement in the substrate. This can be very
> important in applications over concrete where cracking in the concrete
> could result in cracking in the tile.

But is a floating mortar bed also an acceptable way to install natural cleft flagstone upon an on-grade concrete slab that has a long crack?

The crack is the result of movement/settlement, not a controlled cut.

Comment: I've edited for clarity but  the intentional cut by the mason is not a "crack".

Comment: No, but by design that's where most cracks occur.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tech support of a major building products company, it's possible to do a "floating" or "unbonded" mortar bed in this on-grade concrete slab with natural cleft flagstone surface application, but *the mortar bed must be at least two inches thick and have wire reinforcement*.